# How to synthesize mouse clicks in cocoa application?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-graphics

I am trying to write a cocoa application which will automatically perform mouse clicks at specified location. I am creating a `CGEvent` for this mouse click and posting it but for some reason it is not working at all.

Here is my code for mouse click

```
func mouseClick(location: NSPoint) {
    let source = CGEventSource.init(stateID: .hidSystemState)
    let eventDown = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: source, mouseType: .leftMouseDown, mouseCursorPosition: location , mouseButton: .left)
    let eventUp = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: source, mouseType: .leftMouseUp, mouseCursorPosition: location , mouseButton: .left)

    eventDown?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
    usleep(500_000)
    eventUp?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
}
```

When I run this code I do see an error in the console saying "**Sender is prohibited from synthesizing events**", does anyone know about this error and how to fix it?.

Note: I am running this app on macOS 10.14.6(Mojave) also have sandboxing already disabled in Xcode.

Comment: You likely need to add the app to the `Accessibility` permissions panel.

Comment: Thanks @pkamb, I already added my app to `Accessibility` permission panel. But, I was running my app from Xcode and apparently you need to re add your app every time you build it.

Comment: Glad it worked. You should add that as an answer here!